# htaccess hide slash on client input

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I have an url like this:

```
example.com/@/lol
```

is there any way of the client typing it as:

```
example.com/@lol
```

and have it still go to:

```
example.com/@/lol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure, you can use this rule in your site root .htaccess or Apache config (if you have access to it):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?@(.+)$ /@/$1 [L]
```